# PHP Insert File From A Directory

Tags: php, file, insert

I have upload file via FTP in a directory, Now i am try to save that file into database and delete file in FTP Directory... Here is my code

```
$myimage = "C:\upload\satu.xml";;
$image = file_get_contents($myimage);
$content=addslashes($image);

$conn = oci_connect('ARTERI','password','192.168.1.1/Mutual');
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO MMSHOSPITAL.HASIL_PEMERIKSAAN (ID, ID_REGISTRASSI, ID_UNIT_LAYANAN, CONTENT)".
                         "VALUES('1', '172', 'ACT', '".$content."') ");
oci_execute($stid);
oci_close($conn);
```

Help me please... that code is not work to save file in the table of my database..

Comment: y are u saving file only save path to file.

Comment: no, i need save file not just the path..

Comment: How is `CONTENT` defined? Is it LOB?

Answer (score 1):

```
$myimage = "C:\upload\satu.xml";
$image = is_file($myimage);//this return true of false
$content=file_get_contents($myimage);//this reads the content of file as string
```

Comment: this script i have try but invalid value, content column is blob in my table of oracle database

Comment: should i change into another type?

Comment: blob is ok it stores as binary . no problem

Comment: just select the content and display using correct content type .it will work

Comment: STIL ERRORRRORA-01465: invalid hex number in C:\xampp\htdocs\MMSBank\file\upload.php on line 25

Comment: I have change XML file content and then this errorWarning: oci_parse(): ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated in C:\xampp\htdocs\MMSBank\file\upload.php on line 24

Warning: oci_execute() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\MMSBank\file\upload.php on line 25

Comment: actually that has something to do with oracle database .from your forums when inserting blob youu have to use **cast_to_raw**

Comment: did you mean like this $content=cast_to_raw(file_get_contents($myimage)); but that function is not defined in PHP.